# Getting error while running to "runqemu qemux86-64"

Tags: linux, image, yocto, qemu, core-image

I want to run the graphic image of qemux86-64 which I have built with yocto. When I am running command "runqemu qemux86-64" or "runqemu" or "runqemu core-image-minimal" I am getting the following error.

```
nikita@ubuntu:~/yocto/poky/build$ runqemu qemux86-64
runqemu - INFO - Running MACHINE=qemux86-64 bitbake -e ...
runqemu - INFO - Continuing with the following parameters:
KERNEL: [/home/nikita/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/bzImage--5.4.205+gitAUTOINC+aaaf9f090d_8a59dfded8-r0-qemux86-64-20220803111012.bin]
MACHINE: [qemux86-64]
FSTYPE: [ext4]
ROOTFS: [/home/nikita/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/core-image-minimal-qemux86-64-20220803111012.rootfs.ext4]
CONFFILE: [/home/nikita/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/core-image-minimal-qemux86-64-20220803111012.qemuboot.conf]

runqemu - INFO - Setting up tap interface under sudo
[sudo] password for nikita: 
runqemu - INFO - Network configuration: ip=192.168.7.2::192.168.7.1:255.255.255.0
runqemu - INFO - Running /home/nikita/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-helper-native/1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=52:54:00:12:34:02 -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -drive file=/home/nikita/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/core-image-minimal-qemux86-64-20220803111012.rootfs.ext4,if=virtio,format=raw -show-cursor -usb -device usb-tablet -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0   -cpu core2duo -m 256 -serial mon:vc -serial null -kernel /home/nikita/yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/bzImage--5.4.205+gitAUTOINC+aaaf9f090d_8a59dfded8-r0-qemux86-64-20220803111012.bin -append 'root=/dev/vda rw  mem=256M ip=192.168.7.2::192.168.7.1:255.255.255.0 oprofile.timer=1 '

runqemu - ERROR - Failed to run qemu: Could not initialize SDL(x11 not available) - exiting

runqemu - INFO - Cleaning up
Set 'tap0' nonpersistent
```

Only solution I found on internet that i should run nographic image for this which has worked fine for me but my requirement is graphic image for this. Help me to find the solution to run graphic image for this.
Your replies would be appreciated .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yocto "Failed to run qemu: Could not initialize SDL(x11 not > available)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237078/yocto-failed-to-run-qemu-could-not-initialize-sdlx11-not-available)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue recently and got fixed by below step,

Change

`PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-system-native = " sdl"`

to

`PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-system-native = " gtk+"`

in `conf/local.conf`

Now recompile and start runqemu